# Rank window function not giving expected result. Need to fetch the latest record based on status

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below one table which contains `id` which can be multiple along with multiple `p_id` and `status`. But I need to fetch only the latest record based on the `status` column.

For e.g

`id = 1`
For this id we have `p_id` as A1, A1, A2 out of which A1 latest status is completed but A2 is still in Initiated. So, the output for `id` 1 should Initiated.

Similarly for `id = 2` we have to fetch "unsuccessful" record.

In short for each `id` if there are any `p_id` which is not completed then we need to show the latest output.

```
create table test(id number, p_id varchar2(50), status varchar2(50));

insert into test values(1,'A1','Initiated');
insert into test values(1,'A2','Initiated');
insert into test values(1,'A1','Completed');

insert into test values(2,'A1','Initiated');
insert into test values(2,'A2','Initiated');
insert into test values(2,'A2','Unsuccessful');
insert into test values(2,'A1','Completed');
```

My Query-

```
select id,p_id,status from(
select id,p_id,status,
    rank() over(partition by p_id order by insert_time desc)rnk from test order by id
    )  where rnk = 1;

DB Version: OracleLive
```

expected output -

```
+----+------+--------------+
| Id | P_Id |    Status    |
+----+------+--------------+
|  1 | A2   | Initiated    |
|  2  | A2   | Unsuccessful |
+----+------+--------------+
```

I need to check if any of the p_id is completed if yes then need to fetch only initiated row. And if p_id is completed and other p_id is in unsuccessful status then need to print unsuccessful because for that p_id there are no initiated record irrespective of timestamp I need to fetch the desired result based on "Initiated" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
with cte as (
  select id, p_id, status,
  sum(case when STATUS = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID order by insert_time desc) isCompleted
  from test order by id
),
cte2 as (
    select id, p_id, status, isCompleted,
    row_number() over (partition by ID order by
              case when STATUS = 'Unsuccessful' then 1
                   when STATUS = 'Initiated' then 2
              end ) AS status_rank
    from cte
    where STATUS <> 'Completed' and isCompleted = 1 
)
select id, p_id, status
from cte2
where status_rank = 1
order by id
```

Result :

```
ID  P_ID    STATUS
1   A2      Initiated
2   A2      Unsuccessful
```

First, cte is used to see if there are any completed flags per ID, and then cte2 is used to order records by status based on specific order(unsuccessfull first then Initiated), then we will take the latest record.

The order by case can be used when we have to order the data on a conditional basis and define the criteria on which the ordering will be done based on a certain condition.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YUZK6OKN)

Comment: This helps a lot. It would be helpful if you can explain a little bit about the query. In cte2 how it will bring the data in order?

Comment: The order by case will let you specify the order of status you want first, I have updated the query to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Should't you partition on `id` (not `p_id`)?

```
SQL>   SELECT id,
  2           p_id,
  3           status,
  4           RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY insert_time DESC)    rnk
  5      FROM test
  6  ORDER BY id, rnk;

        ID P_ID       STATUS                      RNK
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 A2         Initiated                     1   --> this
         1 A1         Completed                     2
         1 A1         Initiated                     3
         2 A2         Unsuccessful                  1   --> this
         2 A1         Completed                     2
         2 A1         Initiated                     3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now it is a simple task to return only rows that ranked as the highest; you already know how to do that, by using the above query as a subquery.

```
SQL>   SELECT id, p_id, status
  2      FROM (SELECT id,
  3                   p_id,
  4                   status,
  5                   RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY insert_time DESC)    rnk
  6              FROM test)
  7     WHERE rnk = 1
  8  ORDER BY id;

        ID P_ID       STATUS
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 A2         Initiated
         2 A2         Unsuccessful

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the status column is containing 6 other values so whenever for one ```id``` if any ```p_id``` is not completed then we need to display the other status that can be completed, unsuccessful, error etc. and if any of the ```p_id``` is initiated and completed then we need to display Initiated

Comment: Could you edit TEST table contents so that it illustrates what you are saying? That would be *source* data - don't forget to specify desired output!

Comment: I have edited the test table where I need to check if any of the ```p_id``` is ```completed``` if yes then need to fetch only ```initiated``` row. And if ```p_id``` is completed and other ```p_id``` is in unsuccessful status then need to print unsuccessful because for that ```p_id``` there are no initiated record

Comment: irrespective of timestamp I need to fetch the desired result based on "Initiated" value

Comment: @Vicky Can you edit your question by adding those information, so the question can be more valuable and clear, thanks

Comment: @SelVazi I have edited the main question. It would be helpful If I can get some insights

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to ignore `(id, p_id)` with `completed` status. Then for those `incompleted` `(id, p_id)`, you want to know their latest status. If that is what you wish, we can have a query like below:

```
select id, p_id, status
from (
    select 
    id, p_id, status, insert_time,
    row_number() over (partition by id, p_id order by insert_time desc) as rank_
    --rank for selecting the lastest status of incompleted (id, p_id)
    from test 
    where (id, p_id) not in ( -- filter all (id, p_id) that are completed
        select id, p_id
        from test
        where status = 'Completed'
        group by id, p_id
    )
) as rank_table
where rank_=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have edited the question for better clarity